How to set default scanner device in "Document Scanner" on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Recently I have upgraded Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04.
I use "Document Scanner" for scanning and my PC is connected to many scanning devices over the LAN.
When I open Document Scanner, every time it scans for all scanning devices and by default chose the first one in the list. However, I want to set the scanning device that is nearer to me as default device for scanning, which I am unable to do.
I do not find any option in Document Scanner > Preferences to set the default scanner.
I have googled it and tried like adding the IP of the device to /etc/sane.d/saned.conf and setting the SANE_DEFAULT_DEVICE to my desired device details that I get from scanimage -L command. Still It does not work.

How can I set my desired device (WSD EPSON M200 Series-1EC881) as the default scanner?
Thanks

of the devices listed, which one is "the scanning device that is nearer to me as default device for scanning". Please [edit] in to your question. As an aside, I have a single HP Colour Laserjet set as the default printer but I also have the eSCL device listed in Document Scanner. When printing, the default printer is presented but consistently the eSCL device is presnted as the option for scanning.

have you tried adding the printer - renaming it and then setting it as your default printer?

Yes. The device is already added and set as default printer
